# How can I authenticate CICD to use gcloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am planning to run `gcloud` command from CICD and need to authenticate it in order to run the command. I usually use `gcloud auth login` but it requires an interactive action to get the access code from browser.

The CICD I am using is not in GCP. It can be any CICD tools.

What is the right way to do that in CICD without human interaction?

Comment: I guess that you CICD isn't Cloud Build and isn't hosted on GCP right?

Comment: that's right. I am looking for a general solution for CICD.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Jenkins or Gitlab, you can store auth login creds as secrets and use them to login and perform CICD workflows after that.

Jenkins does have few plugins such as [gcloud-sdk](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/gcloud-sdk/)